# Showing images using a template .html file in NGINX

Tags: nginx, server-side-includes

I'm using nginx to run my website's server. I'm currently using SSI (Server Side Includes) to have a common  across the HTML files on my website which is working fine right now. So now I want to have a photo gallery, where the photos are stored in a directory (`/var/www/photos`) and they can be accessed from my website this way: `site.com/photo/PhotoTitle.jpg` would show `/var/www/photos/PhotoTitle.jpg`.

Right now I'm using the following code to achieve this:

```
location /photo {
    root /var/www/photos;
}
```

This works and as expected, if I go to `site.com/photo/MilkyWay.jpeg`, it will point to the image at `/var/www/photo/MilkyWay.jpeg`. However I would like to show the image in a HTML template, so I created a file on my website, photo.html, which would load the image data (title, src, ecc) with SSI. The html works fine on its own. But, I wasn't able to point "`site.com/photo/anything.jpeg`" to `/photo.html` as I would have liked. Ideally, this should do the trick:

```
location /photo {
    ssi on;
    set $photosrc $uri; #variable values are place holders right now
    set $phototitle $uri;
    set $photodesc "";
    alias /photo.html;
}
```

but it just returns a 404 error. I've also tried using `/photo/` and `/photo/*`, although I'm not sure what that would change, but anyway the result didn't change.

How would I go about doing this? Is this out of scope of NGINX? I would like to avoid using a proxy pass with a separate app, since that would be overkill for just one page and using html should work fine. But I'm open to suggestions on that front as well.

Comment: There is something wrong. Your first location cannot work as you've described. Post the full real config as it is.

Answer (score 0):

here is my full config. I've changed it a bit since and it works now:

```
map $request_uri $request_basename {
   ~/(?<captured_request_basename>[^/?]*)(?:\?|$) $captured_request_basename;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8080;

    root /var/www/sito;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        ssi on;
    }
    location * {
        ssi on;
        try_files /$uri /$uri.html /index.html =404;
    }
    location /posts {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2727;
        proxy_redirect  http://127.0.0.1:2727/ /;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;

        proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }
    location /photos {
        root /var/www;
    }
    location /photo {
        ssi on;
        ssi_last_modified on;
        set $photosrc /photos/$request_basename;
        set $phototitle $request_basename;
        set $photodesc "";
        try_files /photo.html =404;
    }
}
```

The problem now is that I need to retrieve information from the EXIF data such as the capture date or the title, but that's out of the scope of this question so I will mark this as solved for now and move on.